# Ordered Bag in UML

Tags: uml, associations, class-diagram

When a UML Class diagram association takes `<orderedSet>` annotation, it seems it means there is an order (yet unknown) between the elements at the end of the association. For example:

```
A ---> <orderedSet> B
```

means that for each a:A, its associated set of elements from B are ordered (e.g., `a --> <b1,b2,b5>`)

**My Question:** How is it possible to define the end of an association to be ordered Bag (multi-Set) in UML? ( in above example context, I am looking for the possibility of `a --> <b1,b2,b1,b5>`).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

See also:

- [uml-diagrams.org: Multiplicity Element](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/multiplicity.html#multiplicity-element)
- Chapter **7.5.3** "Common Structure → Types and Multiplicity → Semantics → Multiplicities" in [www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2/PDF/)