# Precise semantic of annotated associations with { bag } and multiplicity bound constraints

Tags: haskell, uml, associations, class-diagram

Suppose I have   `A ---r1 {bag} [1..2]--> B` in a UML class diagram (that is, r1 is an association from A to B and is annotated with {bag} and multiplicity [1..2].

**My Question:** if a:A is an instance of A, is the following collection valid?

> a.r1={(b1,1),(b1,2),(b2,1)}   //collection contains two copies of b1 and one b2

In other words, multiplicity bounds (i.e., [1..2]) apply to the association when it is interpreted purely as r1:A --> B, or it applies to r1: A --> Bag(B)? In the former interpretation, the above collection is valid, since r1 contains at most two instances of B, but in the latter it is not, since r1 contains three elements of Bag(B)! which interpretation is correct?

Multiplicity constraints in UML are explained in Chapter 7.5.3 of [UML document](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2/PDF/) as I am referred to in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634616/ordered-bag-in-uml).

p.s.1: A similar question arises when we substitute {bag} with {seq}.

p.s.2: I added haskell tag to get comment from large haskell community here as @xmojmr suggested. Thanks to @peter that nicely draw the pictures in his answer.

Comment: Your problem may be warmly received at [cstheory.stackexchange.com](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com) or maybe deciphered here if you add the [haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell) tag as smart-guy attention attractor

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but can I add tags here just for attracting  another communities attention when the question is not directly related. It would be good, but I am worried that I would compromise the stackoverflow rules by doing so. wouldn't I?

Comment: in my eyes you've already compromised the Stack Overflow community and your questions is far from comprehensible practical coding problem. Can you simplify/translate it for non-haskell guys like me.. `UML` talks pictures. Can you translate your `A ---r1 {bag} [1..2]--> B` code into `UML` picture? At the other side of `UML` is some `code`, imagine `C#` code. Can you translate your `a.r1={(b1,1),(b1,2),(b2,1)}` into `C#` code example? It seems that you have doubt which one of 2 possible interpretations is correct. Can you show the 2 cases side by side clearly? (picture+code)*2?

Comment: I think @peter kindly did what you asked. Now the problem is that if I want to implement the picture in his answer, and I have a collection of type bag, putting in this collection two b1 and one b2, violates the constraints or not. There is two interpretation as I wrote in the question: 1) it violates because collection contains three elements. 2) does not violate because there is only two references to B instances in the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in specs, Bag is unordered, nonunique collection.
However this describes the relation between the elements you are pointing to.

So your example can be expressed in either way:
 [image: not the bees]

This means that A has reference to *one* to *two* B instances, and those references are stored in a Bag (or any nonunique, unsorted collection; but that is implementation detail).

To answer your question: no, because the Bag contains three instances of B, whilst the allowed maximum is two B's.

Comment: You wrote my class model "means that A has reference to one to two B instances". In my provided instance, A has references to exactly two distinct B's, but three bag elements. In fact, the bag itself contains two instances of B (i.e., b1,b2) such that whose three elements are built out of these two instances. Actually, confusion still stays on the board. p.s. BTW, Is there any handy tool to draws quickly the useful picture you included?

Comment: Well you chose Bag, which is nonunique, that means that even the same element twice will count as two distinct elements; so A still has three distinct references. If you want not to distinguish the same B's then use Set instead (unique, onordered). I drew those in http://www.umlet.com/ which is a great tool for quick sketching.